# RetryInterceptorBuilder doesn't seem to work

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to use Spring capabilities to handle retries. My ListenerContainer is defined like this:

```
@Bean("myListenerContainer")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer statusCheckcontainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, @Autowired StatusQueueListenerServiceImpl messageService) {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();

        container.setMicrometerEnabled(false);
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(statusCheckQueueName);
    container.setListenerId(statusCheckQueueName);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    container.setAutoStartup(true);
    container.setPrefetchCount(6);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
    container.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful().backOffOptions(statusCheckQueueInitialInterval,
                statusCheckQueueMultiplier, statusCheckQueueMaxInterval).maxAttempts(3).keyGenerator(generator-> 1).build());
                container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter( messageService, jsonMessageConverter()));

        return container;
}
```

I'm forcing a RuntimeException in onMessage method, and what I expect is having only 3 retry attemps, but what I see is that the message is retried until the TTL (3 hours later) is expired.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `MessageRecoverer` to set for that interceptor:

```
/**
 * Callback for message that was consumed but failed all retry attempts.
 *
 * @param message the message to recover
 * @param cause the cause of the error
 */
void recover(Message message, Throwable cause);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-listeners

**EDIT**

Example of stateful retry

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So71710515Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71710515Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    MessageConverter converter() {
        SimpleMessageConverter converter = new SimpleMessageConverter();
        converter.setCreateMessageIds(true);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template, SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory) {
        factory.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
                .recoverer((message, cause) -> {
                    System.out.println(new String(message.getBody()) + " retries exhausted");
                })
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 5000)
                .maxAttempts(3).build());

        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "fail");
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "good");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("foo");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if (in.equals("fail")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: .recoverer() is waiting for MethodInvocationRecoverer<?>. How can I set it with something with the same behavior as RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer? Thanjs again!

Comment: OK. We are talking about different builders. You need to use this for Spring AMQP: `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.RetryInterceptorBuilder` and that one has this option: `public B recoverer(MessageRecoverer recoverer) {`

Comment: I was using the wrong class. But after changed that, the message is consumed only once, and there wasn't any retries.

.stateful()
                .backOffOptions(statusCheckQueueInitialInterval, statusCheckQueueMultiplier, statusCheckQueueMaxInterval)
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .messageKeyGenerator(generator -> 1)
                .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .build();

Comment: Why do you need `stateful`? Also why do you use the same `key` for all the messages?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked using stateless, but stateless blocks the consumer while retrying, right? I can't get it working with stateful. Any ideas? The key = 1 was just a test. I tried with unique keys and it doesn't work.

Comment: See this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#retry. Perhaps you are missing some option yet...

Comment: No case with the stateful option... Any ideas? Have you ever used it with a stateful retrier?

Comment: See this tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/main/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/RetryInterceptorBuilderSupportTests.java. No, I never used stateful, so cannot judge.

Comment: Did you have any trouble with stateless approach considering it takes the threads during waits? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I found it as much better solution. While it blocks a thread for retries on the current message, it doesn't not pull more messages from the broker. So, when the app fails, I don't lose data because it remains in the queue on broker.

Comment: One benefit of using stateful is, if you have a prefetch and don't care about strict ordering, you can process other messages before the failed record is retried. But, the thread will block the same way for the next delay before another rmessage is processed. If the prefetch is 1, or you must use strict ordering, there is no point in using stateful retry.

Comment: I added an example to @ArtemBilan 's answer.